# My BeizerPath is above my labels. How can I make my labels appear above?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm looking to make my dopePointlabel appear above my beizerPath. I created a custom shape and I want my label to appear above it. I tried z-index and that does not seem to work. In what way can I make my Beizer Path below my text so my text is viewable. Thank you in advance.

```
class DemoView: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    var path: UIBezierPath!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func createRectangle() {
        path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0, y: 0.0))

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 300.0))

        //path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height))


        //self.frame.size.height
        path.addCurve(to:CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 300.0), controlPoint1:  CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 400), controlPoint2:  CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 400))

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 0.0))

        path.close()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.createRectangle()

        UIColor.orange.setFill()
        path.fill()

        UIColor.purple.setStroke()
        path.stroke()


    }
}
```

view controller code below

```
let height: CGFloat = 400.0

               let demoView = DemoView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                     y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - height/2,
                                                     width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                     height: height))
            dopepointsNumberLabel.layer.zPosition = 1
               self.view.addSubview(demoView)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
self.view.addSubview(demoView)
```

to

```
self.view.insertSubview(demoView,at:0)
```